# Copy raw data of block device using Java

Tags: java, linux

I have 2 disks in the Linux system, say `/dev/dsk1` and `/dev/dsk2`, and I'm trying to read the raw data from `dsk1` in bytes and write them into `dsk2`, in order to make `dsk2` an exact copy of `dsk1`. I tried to do that in the following way (executed with `sudo`):

```java
import...

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException {
        Path src = new File("/dev/dsk1").toPath();
        Path dst = new File("/dev/dsk2").toPath();
        FileChannel r = FileChannel.open(src, StandardOpenOption.READ, StandardOpenOption.WRITE);
        FileChannel w = FileChannel.open(dst, StandardOpenOption.READ, StandardOpenOption.WRITE);
        long size = r.size();
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
        for (int offset = 0; offset < size; offset+=1024) {
            r.position(offset);
            w.position(offset);
            r.read(byteBuffer);
            byteBuffer.flip();
            w.write(byteBuffer);
            byteBuffer.clear();
        }
        r.close();
        w.close();
    }
}
```

but after writing all the bytes in `dsk1` to `dsk2`, `dsk2`'s filesystem seems to be corrupted. No files can be found in it and if I try to `mkdir` it will say "structure needs cleaning".

I've tested the above code on regular files, like a `text1.txt` containing a few characters as `src` and an empty `text2.txt` as `dst`, and it worked fine.

Did I miss something there when reading & writing raw data on block device?

Comment: This will fail if either disk contains a mounted filesystem

Answer (score 0):

You never check if `read` method read all 1024 bytes, or if `write` method wrote them all. Most likely you're leaving gaps in the copy.

There's no magic involved reading from and writing to devices. The first thing I would try is this:

```
try (FileInputStream src = new FileInputStream("/dev/dsk1");
     FileOutputStream dst = new FileOutputStream("/dev/dsk2")) {
    src.transferTo(dst);
}
```